# Stored procedure where column to ORDER BY depends on input parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedure

I'm getting three inputs and based on those three inputs, I'm returning. Input items may vary, so I used `CASE WHEN` statements here.

Is this code correct? If so, how can I make it more optimized?

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[WP_GetAllItems] 
    @IsActive     bit,
    @OrderMode    bit,
    @OrderBy      varchar(75)
as
Begin 
    Select ItemPartNumber, ItemDescription, CreatedDate, InitialPrice from Items where IsActive = @IsActive order by
    CASE WHEN @OrderBy='ItemDescription' AND @OrderMode = 0 THEN ItemDescription END ASC,
    CASE WHEN @OrderBy='ItemDescription' AND @OrderMode = 1 THEN ItemDescription END DESC,
    CASE WHEN @OrderBy='ItemPartNumber' AND @OrderMode = 0 THEN ItemPartNumber END ASC,
    CASE WHEN @OrderBy='ItemPartNumber' AND @OrderMode = 1 THEN ItemPartNumber END DESC,
    CASE WHEN @OrderBy='CreatedDate' AND @OrderMode = 0 THEN CreatedDate END ASC,
    CASE WHEN @OrderBy='CreatedDate' AND @OrderMode = 1 THEN CreatedDate END DESC,
    CASE WHEN @OrderBy='InitialPrice' AND @OrderMode = 0 THEN InitialPrice END ASC,
    CASE WHEN @OrderBy='InitialPrice' AND @OrderMode = 1 THEN InitialPrice END DESC
End
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your code produces the intended results (I assume you've tested it), but not for the right reasons.

You misunderstood the way `CASE ..  WHEN .. THEN .. END` is intended to be used. Check out [the official documentation.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspxhttps://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) It has examples. There are supposed to be multiple `WHEN .. THEN ..` between the `CASE` and the `END`.

However, since there is just a single `WHEN` clause in each `CASE` clauses, if the `WHEN` clause is not satisfied, then the whole `CASE .. END` clause evaluates to `NULL`. `ORDER BY NULL` has no effect, so it turns out that only the clauses you want to use are being used. Lucky you.

However, it would improve the code to use `CASE` in the way it was intended. I can't do it all at once but I can refactor the code slightly.

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[WP_GetAllItems] 
    @IsActive        bit,
    @OrderMode       bit,
    @OrderBy         varchar(75)
as
Begin 
    Select ItemPartNumber, ItemDescription, CreatedDate, InitialPrice from Items where IsActive = @IsActive order by
    IIF( @OrderMode=0,
        CASE
            WHEN @OrderBy='ItemDescription' THEN ItemDescription
            WHEN @OrderBy='ItemPartNumber' THEN ItemPartNumber
            WHEN @OrderBy='CreatedDate' THEN CreatedDate
            WHEN @OrderBy='InitialPrice' THEN InitialPrice
        END, NULL ) ASC,
    IIF( @OrderMode=1,
        CASE
            WHEN @OrderBy='ItemDescription' THEN ItemDescription
            WHEN @OrderBy='ItemPartNumber' THEN ItemPartNumber
            WHEN @OrderBy='CreatedDate' THEN CreatedDate
            WHEN @OrderBy='InitialPrice' THEN InitialPrice
        END, NULL ) DESC
End
```

Comment: Order by not working in this query.